# jquery removing a class (if it exists and adding a new class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying use jquery to remove a class from an element (not knowing ahead of time if it exists) and add a new element to replace it.

Would this be the best way (I'm skepticle because its not checking to see if the class exists before removing it):

```
$(elem).removeClass(oldClass).addClass(newClass);
```

thanks

Comment: Do you need to know if it has the old class before it removes it?  .removeClass() will succeed whether it exists or not.  In other words, if it exists it gets removed, if it does not exist then it is skipped.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$(elem).removeClass(oldClass).addClass(newClass);
```

This is perfect.  No need to check first; if it's there, it goes, if not, it's already gone.

FYI, you can also toggleClass() and add/remove a class depending on if it's already there or not.

Comment: Keep in mind you can also remove more than one class at a time with removeClass() by listing them out space separated, like $(this).removeClass('one two');

Comment: Just curious, why doesn't it state this in the JQuery documentation (or does it?).  I'm just wondering how I am supposed to know that it doesn't throw an error if the class doesn't exist.  Thanks.

Comment: I double checked it myself to see if they posted a best practice - no luck.  In fact, somebody asked the same question on the documentation page.  I can tell you from my experience that this won't cause problems, and in some respects, this particular function does what you ask it to - it returns the wrapped set, minus the class(es) you ask to remove.  If those classes weren't there to begin with, you still get what you asked for.

Comment: I think Sarfraz's answer is better as it doesn't unnecessarily remove and add classes. Usually this isn't a problem but if you use CSS 3 transitions you could see some unexpected results.

Comment: Be aware that this method might force a repaint depending on the CSS that the classes contain.

Comment: Does it work the same with removing multiple classes if any one of them exists?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if ($(elem).hasClass(oldClass)){
   // it has class
} else {
   // it doesn't have specified class
}
```

> Description: Determine whether any of
>   the matched elements are assigned the
>   given class.

Answer (score 4):

```
toggleClass
```

does what you would expect it to do.